# Primefaces Carousel is not working with ScrollPanel

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, primefaces

I am facing a problem with  component when placed inside a . The carousel wont be able to slide or even change when dropdown page numbers are changed. Following is the sample code which i am working now.

```
<p:scrollPanel>
<p:carousel value="#{abcBean.nameList}" var="foo"
rows="1" effect="fade">
<div>
<div style="width: 830px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<p:outputPanel id="namePanel">
<h:outputText value="#{foo.name}"
style="margin-left:20px;color:red;" />
</p:outputPanel>
</div>
</div>
</p:carousel>
</p:scrollPanel>
```

if the carousel component is inside the scroll panel it wont work, but if we took it outside, it will work perfectly. Currently i am working with primefaces 3.4.1, i had also tried with 3.4.2, but that also had the same trouble.

Primefaces 3.4.1
JSF 2 Mojarra Implementation
Tomcat 7.0.26
JDK 1.7
Win XP 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't resolve the issue, so replaced the Primefaces scrollbar with Jquery tiny scorll http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/. And the carousel worked fine.